# Super old email contacts suddenly appears in my phone contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, email, troubleshooting, active-sync

When I woke up this morning I suddenly had 6 new contacts added to my contact book on my phone. All of them were emails, some of them I recognize from WAY back but I sure haven't had contact with them in a LONG time. I guess they were added in some kind of sync activity, but I'm pretty sure none of these addresses that were added, is featured in any of the accounts I'm currently using (gmail, yahoo) etc. I had contact with these people way before this

Why did this happen?

Is there any way to find out where a specific contact were synced from?

Comment: Probably not. If it is google contacts, maybe contacts.google.com might offer an out-of-android solution.

Answer (score 0):

SO, it turns out these contacts were infact imported from a google account I actually deleted about a week ago (20 days for it to get permanently deleted). I looked into my sync settings on my phone and saw how this old gmail adress were still there with sync activated. I had to re-create the google account, and logon to find these contacts in there.

So apparently my phone suddenly decided to add 6 contacts from a deleted google account. This google account had actually a HUGE contact list synced from WAY back on my old phones and accounts. Now all deleted though